Access: DAO.QueryDef multiple executions, odd behavior
I'm writing VBA code for an Access DB. I'm using DAO.QueryDef to insert values I read from a file. Heres the insert:
Public Const sqlInsertPtfValues As String = "INSERT INTO EPtfValues ([AVIPortfolio], [Aggregation], [CubeType], [ValuationDate], [SensitivityType], [SensitivityLevel], [SourceType], [SourceComment], [VariableName], [VariableValue], [Timestamp]) " _
        & "VALUES (" _
        & "[ptf], " _
        & "[aggr], " _
        & "[ct], " _
        & "[vd], " _
        & "[st], " _
        & "[sl], " _
        & "[srctype], " _
        & "[srcComment], " _
        & "[vn], " _
        & "[vv], " _
        & "[ts]);"

(This is set as a global const string in VBA, working fine in various functions.)
Now, the parameter sl is a positive or negative integer. In my import function, I calculate three different values and want to insert them to the current stress level AND the negative thereof.
Here's the crucial part:
Set insertSensi = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, sqlInsertPtfValues)
...
(other parameters are set in between)
            insert.Parameters("vn") = "XXX"
            insert.Parameters("vv") = xxx
            
            insert.Parameters("sl") = lvl
            insert.Execute
            insert.Parameters("sl") = -1 * lvl
            insert.Execute
            
            insert.Parameters("vn") = "YYY"
            insert.Parameters("vv") = yyy
            
            insert.Parameters("sl") = lvl
            insert.Execute
            insert.Parameters("sl") = -1 * lvl
            insert.Execute
                    
            insert.Parameters("vn") = "ZZZ"
            insert.Parameters("vv") = zzz
            
            insert.Parameters("sl") = lvl
            insert.Execute
            insert.Parameters("sl") = -1 * lvl
            insert.Execute

Now what is odd:
It works fine for XXX, but for all other variables, only the positve level is being inserted.
For XXX I see lvl and -lvl with value xxx in the DB, but for YYY and ZZZ I only see level lvl.
What is going on?
Best,
YeOldHinnerk
PS: As this is from productive code, my sample will be altered - do not assume, that everything is 1:1.
